# Writing to a JSON file and updating said file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following code that will write to a JSON file:

```
import json    

def write_data_to_table(word, hash):
    data = {word: hash}
    with open("rainbow_table\\rainbow.json", "a+") as table:
        table.write(json.dumps(data))
```

What I want to do is open the JSON file, add another line to it, and close it. How can I do this without messing with the file?

As of right now when I run the code I get the following:

```
write_data_to_table("test1", "0123456789")
write_data_to_table("test2", "00123456789")
write_data_to_table("test3", "000123456789")

#<= {"test1": "0123456789"}{"test2": "00123456789"}{"test3": "000123456789"}
```

How can I update the file without completely screwing with it?

My expected output would probably be something along the lines of:

```
{
  "test1": "0123456789",
  "test2": "00123456789",
  "test3": "000123456789",
}
```

Comment: you may read  your rainbow table with `parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)`

Comment: read the json data in, parse it, modify it, write it back out.

Comment: @BryanOakley With the size of this file, that could destroy my computer.

Comment: If you really don't want to parse the file again each time you are updating, you must `seek` the file pointer to just before the closing `}`, write the record and put back the closing `}`.

Comment: Open the file, seek to the end, seek 2 characters back (`\n}`), write `,\n"test1": "0123456789"\n}`, and close the file.

Comment: You should read the `JSON` object from the file. Add the desired key to the JSON structure and re-write the file.

Comment: @L3viathan, that might actually work...

Comment: If you have a computer less than 10  years old, you should be able to load hundreds or thousands of megabytes before running into a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may read the JSON data with :

```
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
```

You now manipulate a classic dictionary. You can add data with :

```
parsed_json.update({'test4': 0000123456789})
```

Then you can write data to a file using :

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(parsed_json, outfile)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rainbow.py", line 37, in <module>
    write_data_to_table("test1", "0123456789")
  File "rainbow.py", line 21, in write_data_to_table
    parsed_json = json.loads("rainbow_table\\rainbow.json")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin is your input file a JSON formated file?

Comment: Yes I am, just ran it through a validator

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the closing "}" is the last byte in the file you can do this:

```
>>> f = open('test.json', 'a+')
>>> json.dump({"foo": "bar"}, f)  # create the file
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.read()
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> f.seek(-1, 2)
>>> f.write(',\n', f.write(',\n' + json.dumps({"spam": "bacon"})[1:]))
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> print(f.read())
{"foo": "bar",
"spam": "bacon"}
```

Since your data is not hierarchical, you should consider a flat format like "TSV".